# Developer Sites contradict each other regading webview-shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: java, android, webview

a lot of Android developer implement their own webview.
Although a lot of questions related to this topic are discussed on stackoverflow, here is probably a cause of this lack of clarity.

To open links within your WebView, android developer define their own webview.

- According to http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html returning `false` in    `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` should be used, to open the url in the current Webview.
  ("current" means presumably created or used lately?)
- According to http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html and various blogs:

  ```
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
     view.loadUrl(url);
     return true;
  }
  ```

  `true` must me returned.

**Is there a mistake in one of the developer sites? It there difference between API level?
What is the cleanest and best use of shouldOverrideUrlLoading?**

An answer would help our team and a lot of other developers working with android webviews.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you decide to implement **WebViewClient**:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
  {
    // My own condition to decide if I should skip URL loading
    boolean avoidURLLoading = ...

    if (avoidURLLoading)
    {
      // Ask the WebView to avoid loading the URL,
      // I want to manage this case on my own.
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      // Let the WebView load the URL 
      return false;
    }
  };
});
```

If you don't implement **WebViewClient**, every time you'll ask the *WebView* to load an URL with the `loadUrl` method, it will ask the *Activity Manager* to find a proper app to load the URL (typically a web browser installed in the device).

The default implementation of **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** in **WebViewClient** is

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
  return false;
}
```

So if you just write something like this

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

the URL will load inside your own *WebView* and not in an external web browser.

You'll typically return `true` in **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** when you want to modify the URL and then load the new one with another `loadUrl` call or when you just want to avoid loading the URL and handle the request in a different way.

The behavior in your example

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
  view.loadUrl(url);
  return true;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
  return false;
}
```

because you're telling the *WebView* to avoid handling the URL loading (`return true`), but you're also making another request with `view.loadUrl(url)` so in fact you end up loading the URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This really clarifies the issue. Great!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to open the link in the current WebView(Not the browser) you sould return false like this:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){

            return false;  

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but on developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/… there is also a custom WebViewClient with return true, so that the current WebView is loaded instead of the browser. It is still unclear whether `return false` or `return true` with `view.load` should be used to open the link in the current WebView.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you implement the setWebViewClient(..) my answer and the axample do the same thing. If you  on the other hand do not implement it the browser will start instaed.